# Is it possible to use Google Cartographer with ROS Noetic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use Google Cartographer with ROS Noetic? In Melodic this all seemed to available out of the box but in Noetic this does not seem to be the case. The installation instructions [here](https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compilation.html) also seem to be outdated. Could anyone confirm this please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365117/is-it-possible-to-use-google-cartographer-with-ros-noetic?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-11-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is, because the repo
https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer_ros

Contains an ros Neotic Docker file.

You May can it read as an instruction how to compile

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-11-09**:
Ok so are you suggesting that I should run it through Docker or manually translate the instructions in the Docker file to terminal commands to do the install?

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2020-11-09**:
Yes. It say it is possible to compile for Neotic

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2021-06-19**:
Great! The instructions I used to do this are [here](https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compilation.html).